# How to crawl data from a library website

Tags: web-crawling, research

I need to crawl research papers, abstracts, titles, and authors and store them for ontological usage. What are the steps to crawl such data?

Answer (score 5):

First, you should check for any license for using the site to see if you can use their data for any reason (commercial and non-commercial).

Second, you should read the terms of use and find anything about scraping website. Many websites don't allow scraping.

Third, if non of the above is a problem, you should use a programming language to crawl and scrap the content from the website. Do you have any knowledge of any programming language?

Comment: Thank you very much, I have a little knowledge about Java or c# but what about web crawler programs such as text crawler or web miner?

Comment: In terms of technical tactics, I highly suggest taking a look at ScraperWiki.com which will host and run your web scraper code and resulting database. You can write scrapers in C#.

Comment: [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) would be a good base, or urllib of BeautifulSoup for python.